# Could a Thread fail to start?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to run some code from a different thread and have it timeout after a set period of time. I also want to be able to periodically run some other code (i.e. refresh some output or something).

This is essentially how I'm doing it:

```
Thread operation = new Thread() { ... };
operation.start();

// Check if Thread is still alive every 100ms
for (int i = 0; i < timeout / 100; i++) {
    somethingToDoWhileWaiting(...);
    if (!operation.isAlive()) {
        break; // Thread is dead so we can end early
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
}

if (operation.isAlive()) {
    operation.interrupt(); // timed out
}
```

My question is, is there any way that the thread can not start (without throwing some sort of exception), or that it might not have started by the time I want to check it's alive?

As in, is there a chance that:

1. I call `operation.start()` and no errors are thrown.
2. I get into the loop and check if it's alive
3. It isn't (either because it hasn't started yet or there's been a behind the scenes error)?

Short of that, is there a better way of checking that a thread has ended (or that it's started correctly - I thought of looping until it was alive, but I have the same worry about that)?

Comment: I feel like you should checkout JDK's Future API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Executors` and `Futures` are the way to go as others have pointed out.

But to specifically answer your question

> is there any way that the thread can not start (without throwing some sort of exception), or that it might not have started by the time I want to check it's alive?

**Answer**: The thread will start or throw an exception. Period.

Checkout the `Thread.start()` method's documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()).

In addition to this, here is the start method's code. You can go through it to get a feel of it.

```
public synchronized void start() {
    /**
     * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
     * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added
     * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
     *
     * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
     */
    if (threadStatus != 0)
        throw new IllegalThreadStateException();

    /* Notify the group that this thread is about to be started
     * so that it can be added to the group's list of threads
     * and the group's unstarted count can be decremented. */
    group.add(this);

    boolean started = false;
    try {
        start0();
        started = true;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (!started) {
                group.threadStartFailed(this);
            }
        } catch (Throwable ignore) {
            /* do nothing. If start0 threw a Throwable then
              it will be passed up the call stack */
        }
    }
}

private native void start0();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This is a great place to use an ExecutorService and Futures:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() { ... };
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<Void> future = executor.submit(task);

// Check if Thread is still alive every 100ms
for (int i = 0; i < timeout / 100; i++) {
    somethingToDoWhileWaiting(...);
    if (!future.isDone()) {
        break; // Thread is dead so we can end early
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
}

if (!future.isDone()) {
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

As to your core question: threads are at the mercy of the operating system's scheduler. A thread *could* never start; however, this is exceedingly unlikely, since the OS scheduler is very good at its job. If an appreciable amount of time passes without a thread doing work, it is much more likely that your code has a bug.

Comment: Shouldn't `get()` be called on the Future, even if it is declared to return `Void`? Otherwise exceptions might be thrown from within the thread and never caught.  And yes, `get()` is a blocking call, and because of this, I usually call it from within a callback method.

Answer (score -2):

Use Thread.join() - it will block until the Thread has exitted.

Comment: That would work in the most basic case, but I don't necessarily want to block execution. There might be things I want to do in the meantime. I'll edit to reflect this :)